# Attacks on WPF applications

Tags: .net, wpf, security

What attacks or security vulnerabilities are specific to WPF applications?
To clarify, I'm not asking how to do SQL Injection on WPF apps, or what kind of crypto should I use, or... I'm also not specifically asking about flaws in the Framework, or in WPF itself, rather flaws that might manifest based on improper implementation.
Very specifically, I'm interested on new attacks, or new vectors, that are particular to a client application implemented in WPF. Not specifically XBAP... ClickOnce related issues would be great too.

---

[WPF Skin Skinning Security Concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610948/wpf-skin-skinning-security-concerns) would be a good example, though not particularly relevant to my specific need (yet still a valid answer).

Comment: I have done some searching and I can't find a single CVE number issued due to a WPF based vulnerability.   This is a good question and I know my answer is not complete.

Comment: @TheRook, I'm also interested in implementation flaws for apps based on WPF, that are caused by unfamiliarity with the way WPF works and its plumbing, not just vulns in WPF itself.

Comment: Yeah I think we are on the same page.  The problem that I see is what can an attacker gain from attacking wpf?  What could be gained from abusing the WPF that couldn't be gained from attaching a debugger?   I don't know much about the windows world,  but it doesn't strike me as being an attack surface (But I could be completely off base here).

Answer (score 2):

With WPF, it's easier for someone to steal your GUI.  In general, though, it may result in better security because WPF controls do not get windows messaging by default.  They use hit testing for dispatching events using routed commands.  As far as windows is concerned, it's a game running in that space, not a windows app.

Comment: Although, in Visual Studio 2010 extensions manager there is a plug-in to help obfuscate your XAML.

Comment: Another consideration is that while the application is blind to windows messaging and associated interfaces, there are programs that will allow you to view the visual tree in WPF.  There is a tool called Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) that can inspect your visual tree for debugging purposes.  This could be cause for concern, but usually it isn't a big deal.

Comment: thanks for the info. Interesting, but doesnt quite help me yet... I'm actually leaning towards accepting that the app is relatively secure :)